# Cmd + Shift + T behaves differently in Safari

Tags: keyboard, safari, shortcut

Recently I started to use Safari instead Opera and if I accidentally close a window in Opera I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and the window reopens.

But when I do the same in Safari a window reopens and closes and deletes from history. Why does it work like that?

Comment: According to [Apple support documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/keyboard-and-other-shortcuts-cpsh003/mac) Shift-Command-T is "Reopen the last tab you closed".

Comment: It does reopen the last tab but also as I said after the tab is reopened it closes automatically and disappears from history

Comment: I can't replicate this on my machine and it's definitely not default behavior. Maybe it's worth to check Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can "Undo Close Tab" via the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

You can also check whether the shortcut of "Reopen Last Closed Tab" is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. If not, change it in **System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**:

- Application: select "Safari.app"
- Menu Title: type "Reopen Last Closed Tab" - from the "History" menu
- Keyboard Shortcut: press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>